# How can store all value in array pressing button inside form.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following html code:

```
Region:<span id="region">Rajkot</span><br>
Activity:<span id="Select">Cricket</span><br>
Radius:<input type="text" id="radius" value="50000"></input><br>
Gender:<select name="Gender" id="Sex">
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
            <option value="3">Both</option>
        </select><br>
Date:<input type="text" id="date" value="2013:04:03 11:54:00"></input><br>
<input type="button" value="Go">
```

I want to store all the values in array on button click.

I want to have the following functionality:
When I click on `go` button, all values of html are store in array.

Comment: putting it on a `<form>` will be much better.

Comment: @jack lanza, Just curious. Where do you live?

Answer (score 0):

Put everythign inside `form` ( I assume you already have one)

```
<form>

Region:<span id="region">Rajkot</span><br>
Activity:<span id="Select">Cricket</span><br>
Radius:<input type="text" id="radius" value="50000"></input><br>
Gender:<select name="Gender" id="Sex">
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
            <option value="3">Both</option>
        </select><br>
Date:<input type="text" id="date" value="2013:04:03 11:54:00"></input><br>
    <input type="button" value="Go">
</form>
```

`$('form').serializeArray();` will do the trick for you.
[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
   $('form').submit(function() {
     $('form').serializeArray();
      return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it using your structure:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JvMFH/2/)

```
//javascript
function gatherData(){
    var arrData = [];
    arrData['region'] = $('#region').html();
    arrData['Select'] = $('#Select').html();
    arrData['radius'] = $('#radius').val();
    arrData['Gender'] = $('#Sex').val();
    arrData['date'] = $('#date').val();
    return arrData;
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
    //add Id or class to the button for better selector
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){ 
        var data =  gatherData();
        console.log(data);
        //alert(data);
    });
});
```

consider using form as other peple sugested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){
$_SESSION["abc"]=array("C", "C++","JAVA","C#","PHP");
 }

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   $aa=$_POST['text1'];

   array_push( $_SESSION["abc"],$aa);
   echo "hello";
    foreach( $_SESSION["abc"] as $key=>$val)
    { 

        echo $val;
    }
  }

 ?>
```